# Add children to XElement via LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a Collection of a class that looks like:

```
public class Group
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

private ObservableCollection<Group> _groups;
```

now I want to create a xml structure from groups that looks like:

```
<Ou>
    <Group>AAA</Group>
    <Group>BBB</Group>
    <Group>CCC</Group>
    <Group>DDD</Group>
</Ou>
```

I have try following:

```
new XElement("Ou", //How continue here?)
```

but do not know how to continue coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var element =
    new XElement(
        "Ou",
        new XElement("Group", "AAA"),
        new XElement("Group", "BBB"),
        new XElement("Group", "CCC"),
        new XElement("Group", "DDD"));
```

Or from your data structure:

```
var element =
    new XElement("Ou",
        from g in _groups
        select new XElement("Group", g.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new XElement("Ou", _groups.Select(g => new XElement("Group", g.Name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
var element = new XElement("Ou");
element.Add(new XElement("Group", "AAA"));
element.Add(new XElement("Group", "BBB"));
element.Add(new XElement("Group", "CCC"));
element.Add(new XElement("Group", "DDD"));
...
```